# Multiple values through email in android

Tags: android, email

I want to send multiple values through EXTRATEXT intent...But I am not able to do it.

Code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
                String mailid="luckshay_sm@yahoo.co.in"; 




  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mailid}); 
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Delivery Request"); 
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My address is   "+edittext.getText().toString());                             

 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "My phone number is "+edittext1.getText().toString());
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")); 
               }

           });

           Now the problem is that only phone number appears but the address doesnt appear..ie. its taking the second EXTRA_TEXT and not the first one.:(
```

I want to pass some 5-6 values using EXTRA_TEXT....Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

if u use 2 (android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) it takes last one.
so,
U use the below code for both address and phone number as putextra

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My address is   "+edittext.getText().toString()+"\n My phone number is "+edittext1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: yeah i can do that but see I want to put Extra_Text in a loop...i want to do something like: for(i=0; i<B.size();i++) {emailIntent.putExta(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"A[i].ToString()}

Comment: for(i=0; i<B.size();i++) {emailIntent.putExta(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"A[i].ToString()} is it working fine?

Comment: did u try my answer.U got the expected result or not?

Comment: yes i did. But this is not what I want...I want it to be in a loop. And its not working that way.